# Take a string, turn it into some DB commands (C#)

Tags: c#, parsing, command

I need to write something in C# that allows users to query data in a human-readable format. So in a textarea, they would type in this:

```
Students.Class, name, address, classid, grade
```

Which would result in:

```
Marcus, 11B Westbury Ave. 200718, A+
```

What the above should do is: Look in the students DB, joining on the class table, then retrieving the name, address, classid, grade.

I have tried writing my own parsing method, splitting the string into an array and then based on the data in the array, querying the database. However, the issue that I am now having is that some users are making mistakes with the syntax:

```
Students, name, address, classid, grade
```

(Missing out the .class bit). So I have to throw try/catch methods and present the User with error messages.

The simple method above works, but I am wondering if there are any libraries out there that will take my string data and do what I am after?

Comment: You basically want to convert a **custom** query language into SQL. Why would you think someone already implemented a converter for *your custom language* as a library? If your simple method works, then what's the problem?

Comment: friend dot forget prove the answer ;) thank you

Answer (score 1):

you want create parse at this way you need to learn **flex and bison**  but there is a links can help you to create that.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664785/A-New-Parser-Generator-for-Csharp